# Fan always run with ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, dell, fan

My laptop is dell vostro 3560. I have just installed ubuntu 12.04 LTS on it, everything is good except fan. It always run, always makes some noises. It's not normal when comparing with windows 8.1. How can it solve this problem? 
CPU's temperature is not high. it's only 47 C

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the solution to your problem is to use 'i8kutils':

$ sudo apt-get install i8kutils

It needs some configuration to work properly.